# How to add a Follow - UnFollow Button on my Website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I want to make a button on my website so that a user can click follow OR Unfollow on a certain game.

Here is my follow Table:
[Follow Button Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uGnZ.jpg)

When a user clicks on the button associated with the game ID, it should insert 1 into the game_follow database for that id.

(I already have a game and users table, and I know how to get each of those ID's)

I know this is a broad question, but maybe someone can point me in the right direction, or show me another tutorial.

EDIT:
This so far isn't working:

Heres my button:

```html
<button class="follow-game" data-game_id="<?php echo $game_id['id']; ?>">Follow!</button>
```

Heres my ajax call:

```html
$(function(){
  $('.follow-game').click(function(){
   follow_game(this);
  });
 });

 function follow_game(obj){
  var game_id = $(obj).attr('data-game_id');

  jQuery.ajax({
   url: 'follow.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: { game_id : game_id },
   success: function(data) {
    alert("You Followed!");
   },
   error: function () {
    alert("Something went wrong with Follow Button.");
   }
  });

 }
```

And here is my follow.php

```html
<?php

    require_once 'core/init.php';

    // Set user_id to the currently logged in user.
    $user_id = $user_data['id'];

    // Set $game_id to the current ID of the game (coming from ajax call)
    $game_id = $_POST['game_id'];

    // Grab the game (ID) from the games table, then Query it.
    //$SQL_SELECT_GAME = "select * from games where id = '$game_id'";
    //$db->query($SQL_SELECT_GAME);

    // Do an update on game_follow table, and set follow = 1 (means that this game is being followed) where the user_id = $user_id and game_id = $game_id, then Query it.
    $SQL_UPDATE = "update game_follows set follow = 1 where user_id = '$user_id' and game_id = '$game_id'";
    $db->query($SQL_UPDATE);
```

My table is the image link above

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a broad question, so, broad answers:

My suggestion would be to attach a javascript listener to the button, which will call an ajax function running a php script, executing the mysql query to update you database accordingly.

For the html:

```
<button class="follow-game" data-game_id="1">Follow!</button
```

For the javascript: (jquery is my preference, so that's my example)

```
$(function(){
   $('.follow-game').click(function(){
      follow_game(this);
   });
});
function follow_game(obj){
game_id = $(obj).attr('data-game_id');

$.ajax({
  url: '/follow.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    game_id : game_id
  },
  success: function(rs){
    alert("yay");
  }
});

}
```

For the PHP/MYSQL:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$game_id = $_POST['game_id'];
$sql = "UPDATE `game_follows` SET follow = 1 WHERE user_id='{$user_id}' AND $game_id='{$game_id}'";
```

Then run the sql with whatever mysql connection/method you're using.
Of course, this doesn't take security into consideration at all, etc, but worry about that once you have the basic functionality down.

Comment: when you wrote data-game_id=1, does that mean you want me to get the game_id like: data-game_id="<?php echo $game['id'];?>"

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would recommend. There's many ways to do it, but I find that to be the simplest.